# React Fetch CORS using proxy works in local not in IIS

Tags: reactjs, iis, create-react-app, url-rewrite-module

Techies,

I have used create react app to create react application where I have 2 components and used react router dom, calling API from different domain so used proxy in package.json.

It works in local, not in IIS

I have deployed the same in IIS and installed URL rewrite module, everything is working fine except API fetch.

web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <rewrite>
         <rules>
            <rule name="React Routes" stopProcessing="true">
               <match url=".*" />
               <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                  <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                  <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
               </conditions>
               <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
            </rule>
         </rules>
      </rewrite>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

api calling method

```
export async function GetStreetNames() {
    const res = await fetch('/Search/getst', {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    });
    var respJson = await res.json();
    console.log(respJson);
    return respJson;
}
```

proxy in package.json

```
  "proxy": "https://api.com/api"
```

Comment: What does it mean that it doesn't work? Is there an error log?

Comment: it means it's not working, there is no error log, it just returns html "You need to enable JavaScript to run this app."

Comment: For information about "Deploy React Application on IIS Server", you can refer to this link: https://medium.com/@sumit.kharche/how-to-deploy-react-application-on-iis-server-a71b09152fa2

Comment: It's not helpful

Comment: This may also be caused by cross-domain. I suggest you install the Microsoft IIS CORS module to enable IIS to support cross-domain: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/cors-module/cors-module-configuration-reference

Comment: the module is to enable CORS for a site, not for CORS request support

Comment: Maybe you can use FRT to troubleshoot this issue: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis